# Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter 64Bit - Apache not starting with PHP module

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, php, php.ini

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter 64Bit.

On it I installed Apache 2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl, the Apache server runs fine without a PHP-module. But when I try to load the php-5.2.17-Win32-VC6-x86 module the Apache server does not start with the error-message "The requested operation has failed!"

in the httpd conf I added

```
# 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

PHP was copied to the folder c:/php/

Has anyone an idea how to start the apache with the php-module?

Answer (score 0):

From https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51516

> **[2013-09-16 08:57 UTC] john at mcmillantech dot co dot uk**
>   There are major compatibility issues with Apache and PHP. You must use the thread safe version of PHP. Only the later versions of Apache work with Windows 7. I have written up some instructions at http://johnrmcmillan.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/installing-apache-and-php-on-windows.<